# dotenv file is not loading environment variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I have .env file at *root folder* file

```
NODE_ENV=development
NODE_HOST=localhost
NODE_PORT=4000
NODE_HTTPS=false
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=user
```

And `server.js` file in the `root/app/config/server.js` folder. 
The first line of `server.js` file is

`require('dotenv').config();`

I also tried following:

`require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'})`;

`require('dotenv').config({path: '../../.env'})`;

*However, my env variable are not loaded when I run the `server.js` file 
from **command prompt***

`node root/app/config/server.js`

If I use the *visual studio* and press *F5*, it loads!!

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, what I'm missing.
Any suggestion is highly appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: The current working directory might be a hint for you.

Comment: Hi @zerkms, not sure I follow you.

Comment: Ok. What is `../.env`? It's a relative path. That is relative to ... what?

Comment: Sorry, I think I should have done `../../.env` (which I also did btw), relative to `server.js` file, since it is called inside server.js file?

Comment: @zerkms I think I got what you mean. It should be relative to the directory where I run `node.exe`. so, in that case, I should run my `node.exe` at the root directory. Is that correct?

Comment: Or you could use absolute paths instead and not rely on current working directory value: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: I believe all the `require(path)` syntax I see over the internet , uses the `relative path`. I always thought it's relative to the script that's calling it. It seems quite confusing to think in terms of `current node process working directory` because it can be any path.

Comment: Unless in your case it's not a `require`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. for `require`, the path is relative to the script itself, however from dotenv, it looks like path is relative to the current working directory. Thanks a lot for helping out!!!!

Answer (score 211, accepted):

How about use `require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/./../../.env'})` ?

Your problem seems to be the execution path.

Comment: That's not going to work. You are mixing absolute and relative path together. You should use Path.Join instead.

Comment: @ZammyPage there is no reason why combining an absolute path and a relative path would not work (if they add the leading slash to the relative path to the env file it must work)

Comment: Sorry I forgot the leading slash :(. I'm using dotenv on my service like this. It doesn`t work?

Comment: **require('dotenv').config({ path: \`${__dirname}/../../config.env\` })** using back-ticks would looks clean

Comment: How do you allow `.env` to be overridden by `.env.local` ?

Comment: Like @ANewGuyInTown commented: dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, "..", ".env" }); an example using path.join

Comment: Omg this answer was so helpful! I was trying to use the syntax `require('dotenv').config(__dirname+'/.env')` for the longest time, not realizing an object is required!

Answer (score 115):

This solved my issues in Node `v8.14.1`:

```
const path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') })
```

Simply doing `require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/./../../.env'})` resulted in a location that resolved as `/some/path/to/env/./../../.env`

Comment: Thanks for the resolution and it worked for me. In my case I created one file in Controller folder and tried to output the require('dotenv').config() --> It was showing me "c:\users\..\controller\.env". Really weired, why it is referencing controller folder instead root path. 
But when tried with Absolute path(Just for temporary workaround) it worked.

Comment: @ashishsarkar - how does your path string look like? Inside your `config` method?

Comment: @DavidP Finally working solution,does that aproach works well also in production?

Comment: @Goran_Ilic_Ilke - assuming your prod have the same structure, then it should.

Answer (score 29):

Here is a single-line solution:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: require('find-config')('.env') })
```

This will recurse parent directories until it finds a .env file to use.

You can also alternatively use this module called [**ckey**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckey) inspired from one-liner above.

.env file from main directory.

```
# dotenv sample content
USER=sample@gmail.com
PASSWORD=iampassword123
API_KEY=1234567890
```

some js file from sub-directory

```
const ck = require('ckey');

const userName = ck.USER;     // sample@gmail.com
const password = ck.PASSWORD; // iampassword123
const apiKey   = ck.API_KEY;  // 1234567890
```

Comment: how do you use this in a .env file?  To map it to a js file in a sub-directory?  Trying to do this: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/config.json`

Comment: Do you need to npm install find-config as I'm getting Error: Cannot find module 'find-config'?

Answer (score 24):

If you are invoking `dotenv` from a nested file, and your `.env` file is at the project root, the way you want to connect the dots is via the following:

```
require('dotenv').config({path:'relative/path/to/your/.env'})
```

Comment: AFAIK, dotenv takes only an absolute path and note a relative path.

Comment: you're right.. but the path is relative to where the process is run from, and not the file in which dotenv is being called. That was what happened when I was debugging this.

Comment: This fixed my problem with "undefined" .env variables. I even have another project running with the same exact setup for configuring server and dotenv and couldn't get it to work without explicitly defining the path.

Answer (score 19):

One of the comments in @DavidP's answer notes logging the output of dotenv.config with

```
console.log(require("dotenv").config())
```

This will output a log of the config and display errors. In my case it indicated the config method was referencing the current directory instead of the
parent directory which contained my .env file. I was able to reference that with the following

```
require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'})
```

Comment: Strange enough, logging it shows the correct data in an object named "parsed" as in `{ parsed: {} }` But, reading any variable using `process.env.name` still says undefined.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I know this comment is very old but I'd like to respond to add some clarity to that issue for others. If you're using a front-end framework like React or Vue you need to include a prefix to the name of the variable. For React it is "REACT_APP_*YOUR_VARIABLE*" Vue is "VUE_APP_*YOUR_VARIABLE*"

Answer (score 14):

I've had this problem and it turned out that REACT only loads variables prefixed with REACT_APP_

VueJs can have a similar issue as it expects variables to be prefixed with: VUE_APP_

Answer (score 11):

Be sure to load `.env` at the beginning of the entry file (e.g. `index.js` or `server.js`). Sometimes, the order of execution loads the environment variables after the services are initiated. And, by using `__dirname`, it can easily point to the file required relative to the current file.

Here my project structure is like this.

```
.
├─ src
│  └─ index.ts
└─ .env
```

```js
// index.ts
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config({path: path.join(__dirname, '..', '.env')});

...
```

Comment: Not working in Node TS.

Comment: put your dotenv config in another module file and import it when you need

Answer (score 10):

In the remote case that you arrive till this point, my issue was quite dumber:
I wrongly named my env variables with colon ":" instead of equals "=". Rookie mistake but the resulting behavior was not loading the misspelled variables assignment.

```
# dotenv sample content

# correct assignment
USER=sample@gmail.com

# wrong assignment (will not load env var)
USER : sample@gmail.com
```

Comment: I did the same thing. Copied from a JSON object and forgot to format it. Thanks for saving me from another 2 hours of banging my head

Answer (score 8):

You can first debug by using:

```js
console.log(require('dotenv').config())
```

In my scenario, my `.env` file is in root directory and I need to use it in a nested directory. The result gives me:

```
{
  parsed: {
    DATABASE_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/vidly',
    PORT: '8080'
  }
}
```

So I simply parse the result and store it in a variable:

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config().parsed;
```

Then access my DATABASE_URL like a JS object:

```js
dotenv.DATABASE_URL
```

Comment: Thank you so much; Firstly It showed an error, that expected the env to be in src. But now I could track it with ease

Answer (score 6):

This solved the issue for me:

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({
  path: path.resolve('config.env'),
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: process.cwd() + '/config/config.env' });
```

worked for me idk how??

Answer (score 5):

It took me a few head scratches, and the tip to log the output of the require statement to console was really helpful. `console.log(require('dotenv').config());`

Turns out I was running my app from my user/ directory with `nodemon application_name/.` and that was making dotenv look for the .env file in my home dir instead of the app's. I was lazy by skipping one `cd` and that cost me a few minutes.

Answer (score 5):

```
  const path = require('path');
  const dotenv = require('dotenv');
  dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../config.env') })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: It works . You need to  import path from "path";

Answer (score 5):

I found an option `debug: true` to be sent in the config

```
dotenv.config({ debug: true });
```

which showed me the following:

```
[dotenv][DEBUG] "PORT" is already defined in `process.env` and was NOT overwritten
```

I added `overwrite: true` and got it working:

```
[dotenv][DEBUG] "PORT" is already defined in `process.env` and WAS overwritten
```

I know I might be too late answering, but decided to share my findings after hours of checking the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In my case `.env` was read fine, but not `.env.local`.

Updating `package.json` to name `.env` into `.env.local` ( `cp ./.env.local .env`) solved the problem:

```
  "myscript": "cp ./.env.local .env && node ./scripts/myscript.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

if config.env file and index.js file both present in the same directory:
[image]

then, file: index.js

```
const path = require('path'); 

//  Set port from environment variables
dotenv.config({path: 'config.env'})
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
```

file: config.env:

```
PORT = 4000
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with the file **encoding** of the `.env` file in windows. It was encoded in **UTF-16LE**. The file was parsed but it was considered empty. After i converted the `.env` file to **UTF-8** everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you are installed `dotenv` as production dependency. Then, it may not work properly. The `.env` file is commonly utilized during **development** when using `dotenv` to import environment variables into the application's environment. So,

```js
npm install --save-dev dotenv
```

Not that:

```js
npm install dotenv
```

To working properly of `dotenv` library, you always need to mention that code:

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config();
```

In **Top** of the file like this:

[image]

If you put that configuration in the middle. Then, you will see some **wired behavior**. Like, in some file `env` variable working file. But, in some, it is not.

Comment: This actually worked!!! thanks. I called the dotenv.config() before every code but after the import of a router file which caused the error. FYI

Answer (score 1):

You can need the path of the .env file relative to the current working directory from where the application was launched.
You can create this path like this:

```
const path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({path: path.relative(process.cwd(), path.join(__dirname,'.env'))});
```

`process.cwd()` returns the absolute path of the working directory.
`__dirname` returns the absolute path of the application.
`path.join()` adds the path of the .env-file to the path of the application. so if your .env file is nested deeper, just add the folders (e.g. `path.join(__dirname, 'config', 'secret','.env')`)
`path.relative()` creates the relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript.

if you are trying to resolve __dirname and you are compiling your source folder in another folder, make sure that you edit __dirname. in my case i am compiling ts in dist folder and env files are not located in dist folder, but in the root folder. so you should delete /dist from __dirname. To debug it, you can call error() function which returns error if there is problem with reading env file.

```
require('dotenv').config({
    path:  __dirname.replace('\dist','') + `${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`
  }); # To debug .error()
```

another thing, when you set env variables make sure that following:
no space between variable and (&&) as following

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production&& node dist/index.js",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

One time I have got the same problem. Dotenv did not load .env file. I tried to fix this problem with a path config, to put .env file in a root folder, to put .env in the folder where the file is running and nothing helps me. Then I just trashed Node_modules folder, reinstall all dependencies and it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

I'am using:

```
import findUp from 'find-up';
dotenv.config({ path: findUp.sync('.env') });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me using **Playwright** / **typescript**:

1 create file and place at the root of the project: `global-setup.ts`
add inside:

```
async function globalSetup() {
  // Configure ENV variables
  require('dotenv').config()
}

export default globalSetup
```

2 Then use this file into `playwright.config.ts`

as: `globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup'),`

In this way, global conf is created, and pickup in every single test.

Answer (score 0):

For ES6 you need to do this way:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as path from 'path';

dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '..', '.env.testing') });
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me until I finally added `override: true`

Here is my full code

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env'), override: true })
```

Answer (score -1):

Use only absolute path if you are using some other tool(installed globally) to call your config file somewhere ...

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: '/path/to/my/project/.env',
});
```

Answer (score -2):

In .env file use "=" to define key value do not use colon ":"

For example below is incorrect

**USER:root**

This is correct way to define env variables in .env file

**USER=root**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

My failer was the path keyword . should be the P not capital Letter . that was so funny

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33565965)