# Getting an error while connecting MongoDB: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I want to connect my database using .env file but I am getting an error:
[image]

I tried console logging my .env variable but I am getting Undefined:
[image]

Here are my scripts:

**server.js**

`````
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config.env" });
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

// Connect DB
connectDB();

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/auth"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Sever running on port ${PORT}`)
);

console.log("```` DB NAME ````", process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION);

process.on("unhandledRejection", (err, promise) => {
  console.log(`Logged Error: ${err.message}`);
  server.close(() => process.exit(1));
});
`````

**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: true,
  });

  console.log("MongoDB Connected");
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

**config.env**

```
PORT=5000

DATABASE_CONNECTION=mongodb://localhost:27017/node_auth
```

I have checked other solutions, but none of them helped.

Comment: Try wrapping "mongodb://localhost:27017/node_auth" in quotes in the config.env file.

Comment: Nope, still getting an error.

Comment: I looked around and I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335016/dotenv-file-is-not-loading-environment-variables). I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, rename `config.env` to `.env`

Comment: @MsonC So, I tried but I am getting syntax error, am I writing it right?
`require('dotenv').config({C+'/Users/.../auth/config.env'})
`

Comment: @HanielBaez Hi, renaming the file didn't worked

Comment: Ok, It Worked!. Thank you so much @MsonC. Correct way to write it was:  `require("dotenv").config({ path: "C:/Users/.../auth/config.env",});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path:
    "C:/Users/.../auth/config.env",
});
```

Basically, write whole path of the file.