# not able to load .env file using dotenv in nestjs nodejs

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, nestjs, dotenv

I am using nestjs for my nodejs project, and I want to load the `.env` file from outside of the project.

Here is the directory structure

```
.env
services
  /nodejs
     /my-apis
       /src  
         /main.ts
```

and in my `main.ts`

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config({ path: `../../../../.env` });
console.log("process.env.PORT", process.env.PORT);
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix("/api");
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
}
```

but it is not getting the values from `.env`, what can be the issue?

Comment: if you want a more idiomatic solution: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading the `env` file in `main.ts`. My `app.module.ts` was using some env variable to initialize Mongo.

So In my `app.module.ts` env variable was undefined. So I loaded the `env` in `app.module.ts` instead of `main.ts`

Also I used `__dir_name` for path

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/../../../../.env` });
```

and this worked.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335383/10562569

```
require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/./../../.env'})
```

This might help. Customize it to your need.