# Hardhat compile error with API_URL and Private Key import

Tags: javascript, solidity, nft, hardhat

Tying to follow a basic [NFT tutorial](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-write-and-deploy-an-nft), and I have to say, that I am kind of a noob in Programming. The problem that I am facing is that my hardhat.config.js file needs an API_KEY and a Private Key, which it should import from the process.env file:

```
API_URL = "https://ethropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/UkW3oySI7WxvFwDwopQHPOHajHaWFZFv"
PRIVATE_KEY = "8d33c2613cb63d0dc6305e57..."
```

the hardhad config file looks like this:

```
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
*/
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.0",
  defaultNetwork: "ropsten",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    ropsten: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    }
  },
}
```

But whenever I try to compile it and run it tru my deploy.js file I get an error message that essentially tells me, that the import was not possible, and looks like this:

```
  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.ropsten.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid value {"accounts":["0xundefined"]} for HardhatConfig.networks.ropsten - Expected a value of type HttpNetworkConfig.
  
To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH8 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
simon@MacBook-Pro-von-Simon test_fractals % npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten
An unexpected error occurred:

simon@MacBook-Pro-von-Simon test_fractals % npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten
An unexpected error occurred:

simon@MacBook-Pro-von-Simon test_fractals % npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten
An unexpected error occurred:

ReferenceError: API_KEY is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/simon/test_fractals/hardhat.config.js:37:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at importCsjOrEsModule (/Users/simon/test_fractals/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/config/config-loading.ts:23:20)
    at Object.loadConfigAndTasks (/Users/simon/test_fractals/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/config/config-loading.ts:66:18)
    at main (/Users/simon/test_fractals/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/cli.ts:129:20)
simon@MacBook-Pro-von-Simon test_fractals % npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten
An unexpected error occurred:

ReferenceError: API_KEY is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/simon/test_fractals/hardhat.config.js:37:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at importCsjOrEsModule (/Users/simon/test_fractals/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/config/config-loading.ts:23:20)
    at Object.loadConfigAndTasks (/Users/simon/test_fractals/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/config/config-loading.ts:66:1
```

I first thought, that my .env file was not at the right place or that the syntax was not right, but after trying everything I could think of, I still get the same error message. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

I solved the same problem by using this in the `hardhat.config.js` file:

```
require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/.env'})
```

Instead of:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

For more information, you can visit
[dotenv file is not loading environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335016/dotenv-file-is-not-loading-environment-variables)

Comment: That works, although instead of concatenation with `+` I would use `path.join`.

`const path = require('path');`
`require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '/.env') });`

Answer (score 2):

I ran in the same issue and I've solved it in a next way.
The things back to normal when I firstly require the dotenv and only then set config params.

So, the final code looks like that:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});
const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
```

hope this save some time for someone =)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```js
    /**
     * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
     */

     require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/.env'})
     require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers")
     
     const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env

     module.exports = {
      solidity: "0.7.3",
      defaultNetwork: "ropsten",
      networks: {
        hardhat: {
        },
        ropsten: {
          url: "https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/your-api-key", 
// Replace your-api-key with your API key
// Your API_URL also stored in .env file but for simplity I have directly a string here
          accounts: ["klaouoq84qoir983n2nc3234xn98349nx4u2394u23998x3n3"], // This is YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY from Metamask which you can store in env file but for simplity I have directly a string here
        },
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I added 'export' in front of my environment variables.
Once I removed "export" I was able to access them from hardhat config

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30790021)

Answer (score 0):

```
> npm i dotenv


require('dotenv').config()
...
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 80001
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: `https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_WALLET]
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve these problem I install dotenv extencion

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

And in hardtat.config I use process.env.YOUR_CONST

```
 /**
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
*/

require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  defaultNetwork: "goerli",
  networks: {
     hardhat: {},
     goerli: {
        url:process.env.API_URL,
        accounts: [`0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}`]
     }
  },
};
```