# Reference error: API_URL_KEY is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, hardhat, .env

hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
 solidity: "0.8.18",
};

/* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig*/
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require('dotenv').config(); 
const { API_URL_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env; 
module.exports = {   
  solidity: "0.8.17",   
  defaultNetwork: "goerli",   
  networks: {      
    hardhat: {},      
    goerli: {         
     url: API_URL_KEY,         
     account: [`${PRIVATE_KEY}`]      
   }   
 },
   }
```

.env

```
PRIVATE_KEY=b14......3f
API_URL_KEY=https://alien-few-river.ethereum-goerli.discover.quiknode.pro/..../
```

> > npx hardhat compile
> > An unexpected error occurred:

ReferenceError: API_URL_KEY is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hardhat compile error with API\_URL and Private Key import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525606/hardhat-compile-error-with-api-url-and-private-key-import)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to move the import of dotenv (`require('dotenv').config();`) all the way to the top of your file, or at least before the import statement of the hardhat toolbox (which in your case, is at the top of your file)

Comment: Still shows same error

Comment: Have a look at the linked question in the comment on your post

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to set the path of the env file in the config parameter

```
require('dotenv').config({path: "the/path/used.env");
```

[As is suggested on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) if your file containing environment variables is named or located differently.