# npm- Using dotenv in test script to access env variables from file

Tags: npm, webdriver-io, npm-scripts, dotenv

I am running some UI tests using WebdriverIO using npm.

My `.env` file:

```
VARIABLE=SOME-VALUE
```

`package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "dotenv -e .env tsc && wdio wdio.conf.ts"
  },
```

How I am accessing the variable:

```
const myVariable = process.env.VARIABLE
```

All three files are in same directory. When I console log the `myVariable`, i get `undefined`.
I am not getting what is missing. I referred few answers here, but they are not helping.

Also, if someone could throw light on do we need to/how to import the file.
I am fairly new to this, hence any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dotenv file is not loading environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335016/dotenv-file-is-not-loading-environment-variables)

Comment: @cinnaroll45 I checked this link. This isn't helping me.

Answer (score 0):

In WebDriverIO 8 it now [loads `.env`. files automatically](https://webdriver.io/docs/parameterize-tests/#env-files). Your example  `package.json` would then change to the following and everything should work:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "wdio run wdio.conf.ts"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from wdio 8.6.9 to 8.31.1 fixed this for me (no dotenv package required). Perhaps give that a try.

Here's what's in my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@wdio/browserstack-service": "8.31.1",
  "@wdio/cli": "8.31.1",
  "@wdio/local-runner": "8.31.1",
  "@wdio/mocha-framework": "8.31.1",
  "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.31.1",
  "chromedriver": "^121.0.0",
  "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1"
}
```