# environnement variable not loading using javascript, node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables, dotenv

I want to store variables in my .env file and use them instead of using my sensitive data in the code.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
//call express methode to creat the app
const app = express();
//mongoose import to work with the data base
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
//get access to path
const path = require("path");
//intercept any request containing json() content and put it in the request body (same as body parser)
app.use(express.json());
//=======data base connection========
//store our values away, in the .env

const mongUser = process.env.USER_MON;
console.log(mongUser);
```

Here is the code. (there is some other stuff lower but it's this part that is not working.

When I try to console log the general env with `console.log(process.env)` I get everything except what is inside my env file (at the root of the repo):

```
JWT_KEY=HYinity764knn9
USER_MON=myUserName
```

I can't see those variable in the console, i don't understand why they aren't loading. what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dotenv file is not loading environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335016/dotenv-file-is-not-loading-environment-variables)

Answer (score -1):

try to specify exact path to your .env file like this

```
dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/../../.env.dev` })
```

Comment: did not work but i found something else, thks tho

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

this solved it

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') })
```

i already had `const path = require('path')` so i just put it in

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).