# Getting undefined value of .env in nodejs

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, undefined, dotenv, undefined-variable

I am getting "undefned value of .env in nodejs. my .env file is on root directory.need help

my code for .env file:-

```
SECRET_KEY=mynameissuky
```

my app.js file:-

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.SECRET_KEY);
```

installed package - npm i dotenv

Comment: Maybe this will help with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335016/dotenv-file-is-not-loading-environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

In the dotenv documentation, it is shown that the .env file is assumed to be in the current directory.

> Path Default: `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')`

`process.cwd()` method returns the current working directory of the Node.js process.

> Specify a custom path if your file containing environment variables is
> located elsewhere.
>
> `require('dotenv').config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })`

In your case, because your env file is located in the root directory you should specify a custom path for the `.env` file.

For example, my `github.env` is placed in the root directory and I use dotenv as following:

`require('dotenv').config({path:'github.env'});`

Comment: issue not resolved. getting undefined value again

Comment: @sandygill make sure you write the right path

Comment: yes, I added right path

Comment: please, move the  `.env ` file to the root directory and check this `require('dotenv').config({path:'github.env'});`

Answer (score -2):

Try this one

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
```

You will get your environment variable for sure.

Comment: What does this add over the existing answer from 2022?