# Running 'npm run' with specific env file using dotenv

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dotenv

I am currently working on a reactjs project which has been created with `create-react-app`. `env-cmd` package is a little too old and is not under maintenance anymore so I'd like to use `dotenv` instead. Is there a way that I can specify a `.env` file just like we usually do with `env-cmd` but with the help of `dotenv` instead? Or is there a suggested method I should be following using `dotenv`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dotenv file is not loading environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335016/dotenv-file-is-not-loading-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path with .config({path: "directory"})

```
    // Using require syntax    
    require("dotenv").config({ path: "../.env" });
    
    // Using import syntax
    import dotenv from "dotenv"
    dotenv.config({path: "../.env"})
```