# Why does dotenv working on some of the files?

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

I'm creating an express application

I have a main.js file where is imported the app from express

Other called app.js where is defined the middlewares and what routes use

And other files

The import of dotenv is in the app.js, for that, main.js and app.js can reach the process.env variables but I can't do that the other files that are sync with the project get the env variables

What I am missing?

**main.js** , this work fine

[image]

**app.js**, this also work fine

[image]

**other files**, here start to break
[image]

Any ideas of what is happening? :C Or how I can set the dotenv as a Global variable for all the project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the only way it worked for me is by replacing `import dotenv from 'dotenv'` then `dotenv.config()` by `import "dotenv/config.js";`

Comment: For me, I had to drop the `.js` extension and use `import 'dotenv/config'`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving your .env up a directory to be in the root instead of /src.  I think that is where it expects it to be.  If you want to have it somewhere else you can set that in the config.

`Default: path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')`

Specify a custom path if your file containing environment variables is located elsewhere.

`require('dotenv').config({ path: '/src/.env' })`

Comment: Thanks for the answer zac! But the .env is in the root directory :C!

Comment: Oh oops sorry I misread your screenshot.  Hmm that is odd, I will think about it and update if I think of anything.

Comment: Restart everything if you added those env files later as maybe system doesnt know about them.  Could also try defining the path in config to be absolute.

Comment: Can turn on debug see if it shows path you expect : 
 require('dotenv').config({ debug: true }) 

Docs talk about this issue and link to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335016/dotenv-file-is-not-loading-environment-variables a lot of good suggestions.. maybe try `require('dotenv').config({ path: require('find-config')('.env') })
`

Comment: Zac, thank you agasin for the answer. Tomorrow i will be doing the debug, its late now haha. 

I found a walkaround for this and it was just to add in the package.json in the script start -r dotenv/config. This way dotenv will charge for all the project itself.

Not the idea, but works