# In node.js .env file not working correctly, so can I solve it?

Tags: node.js, dotenv, .env

I have a **.env** file in my project located in the same file where server.js does.

But it server.js file **does not see** this file.
When I test, I always get '***undefined***'.

This is my *server.js* file:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const chats = require("./data/data");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

require("dotenv").config();
connectDB();
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// test 1
// test1: undefined
//        ^^^^^^^^^
console.log(`test1: ${process.env.PORT}`);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("API is running");
});

app.get("/api/chats/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(chats);
});

app.get("/api/chats/:id", (req, res) => {
  const chat = chats.find((chat) => chat._id === req.params.id);
  res.send(chat);
});

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

This is .env:

```
PORT=5000
```

Also, this is how the root looks like:

```
|backend
      |.env
      |server.js
```

I tried this but did not help.

`require("dotenv").config({ path: "path/to/file" });`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dotenv file is not loading environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335016/dotenv-file-is-not-loading-environment-variables)

Comment: @about14sheep, thanks for reply.
require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/./../../.env'})

this line of code did not help me. may be I am doing something wrong with __dirname.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1xI.png

Comment: because `/./../../.env` is not the relative path to *your* .env file. use the relative path to *your* .env file. that looks to be `./.env`

Answer (score -1):

I found the error.

My project directory was 'chat'.

So I should have put my .env in the root but not in the 'backend' directory.