# Why couldn't JS file detect a variable from .env file? (dotenv)

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

#### Problem:

The server cannot detect `process.env.PORT` from my .env file, saying `PORT=5000`, and I have dotenv installed. `process.env.port` returns `undefined` Is something wrong?

---

I have a very basic express server that runs fine:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// sendFile will go here
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);
console.log(process.env.PORT)
```

On server start:

```bash
Server started at http://localhost:8080
process.env.PORT = undefined
```

`console.log(process.env.PORT)` on the bottom of express script returned `undefined`

---

I have dotenv installed, proof:

```bash
$ npm ls dotenv       
eloquent-javascript@ /Users/dana/code/eloquent-javascript
└── dotenv@16.0.3
```

My .env file has the following content:

```
PORT=5000
```

#### What is wrong with my setup?

I have express.js, .env and installed `dotenv` via npm.

**Question: Why couldn't `express.js` grab my variable via `process.env.PORT` from the `.env` file?**

Comment: This has been answered in the past https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335383/8605717

Answer (score 0):

you need yo configure dotenv.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

```
 dotenv.config();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
```

with this:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```