# Having troubles with the .env file

Tags: node.js, backend, dotenv, .env

I am using dotenv in node and my .env is in a config folder (I don't know if that is best practice though) and I am not able to import my API key I have in it to another file (in this case, the weather.js in the routes folder)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARbiq.png)

When I put the API key manually in the Url, it works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RQYy.png)

I tried changing the folder location of the .env file and I tried some configurations of the require('dotenv').config()

Comment: Don't show images of text. [Show the actual text](/help/how-to-ask). Not having clicked on them: did you remember to specify the `path` to your file in dotenv's config()? If not, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335016/dotenv-file-is-not-loading-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

You can try define the path in config `require('dotenv').config()`

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as path from 'path';

dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '..', '.env.testing') });
```

For more detail see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77631539/6754506